# How do I add an extra column to the results of a GROUP BY with a value that matches a condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying to use GROUP BY to generate a summary of a table, but I want to add a column with a value that matches a condition from the original table.  The condition I want to check for is that style = 2 so that a new column with the filename that matches that style is shown in the results.

This is what the original table looks like:

```
category  |  value | style | filename
   A      |   8    |   0   |   AAA    
   B      |   4    |   2   |   BBB    
   B      |   6    |   1   |   CCC    
   A      |   3    |   2   |   DDD    
   A      |   6    |   1   |   EEE    
   C      |   7    |   2   |   FFF   
   B      |   5    |   1   |   GGG    
   A      |   3    |   1   |   HHH
```

This is what I want:

```
category  |  total_value   | filename
   A      |        20      |   DDD
   B      |        15      |   BBB
   C      |         7      |   FFF
```

I tried this query, but the filename chosen was the MINIMUM, not the one that matches style = 2:

```
SELECT category, SUM(value) AS total_value, MIN(filename) AS filename FROM data GROUP BY category;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you need this:

```
SELECT category, SUM(value) AS total_value, 
MIN(case when style = 2 then filename end) AS filename 
FROM data GROUP BY category;
```

Answer (score -1):

Although I like the answer of @Oto Shavadze better, I still like to share a solution I thought of:

```
select data.category, SUM(data.value), hlp.filename
from data 
left join ( 
    select category, filename
    from data 
    where style = 2 
    group by category
    limit 1
) as hlp
on data.category = hlp.category
group by data.category
```

This solution uses a subquery, which will select the respective `filename` for each `category`.

**EDIT:**

Looks like the website I used was not verry restrictive, in the use of colum not beeing listed in the group by or beeing in an aggregate function.

So here the updated version, using the MIN() function on filname, as i said in comments:

```
select data.category, SUM(data.value), MIN(hlp.filename)
from data 
left join ( 
    select category, MIN(filename) as filename
    from data 
    where style = 2 
    group by category
) as hlp
on data.category = hlp.category
group by data.category;
```

Comment: query is invalid that is not how you should use GROUP BY.. This would give *"ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column '<column_name>' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"* on the more modern MySQL versions..

Comment: Well I tried my query out on some website and it woked perfectly, I don´t realy see where a false use of group by should be. Tho you could add a MIN() to the hlp.filename, but it should work without it aswell

Comment: *"Well I tried my query out on some website and it woked perfectly,"* Well not here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/swiekcJdnmkDsniXhoAjL8/1

Comment: *"I don´t realy see where a false use of group by should be"* *"SQL-92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause. For example, this query is illegal in standard SQL-92 because the nonaggregated name column in the select list does not appear in the GROUP BY: "* see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) to add to @Strawberry 's comment

Comment: Yeah well ok, still the query is correct, when using MIN() on filename, as I said. The engine I used was not verry restricitve and just used min by default i guess.

Comment: *"The engine I used was not verry restricitve and just used min by default i guess."* No it's not using a MIN() as defualt just a non deterministic(random) value was choosen which does not even related to the group or NULL when there is no such value.. If your statement is true both statements should have the same results in this [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t5PtEPPpcHk2tZAB7E6z6M/2) notice i turn the strictness off

Comment: *"Yeah well ok, still the query is correct, when using MIN() on filename, as I said."* But yes your second query is correct